# A java string exercise i came across

Tags: java, string

Look for patterns like "zip" and "zap" in the string -- length-3, starting with 'z' and ending with 'p'. Return a string where for all such words, the middle letter is gone, so "zipXzap" yields "zpXzp"

Here is a solution i got from someone:

```
public class Rough {
    public static void main(String [] args){
        StringBuffer mat = new StringBuffer("matziplzdpaztp");
        for(int i = 0; i < mat.length() - 2; ++i){
            if (mat.charAt(i) == 'z' & mat.charAt(i + 2) == 'p'){
                mat.deleteCharAt(i + 1);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(mat);
   }
}
```

But why is it that the for loop condition (i < mat.length() -2) is not (i < mat.length())????

Comment: Because in each loop you look at positions i, i+1, and i+2. If i == n, i + 1 would be out of bounds. Besides, if you only have 2 characters left to look at, they definitely aren't of the form z*p since that has a min 3 characters.

Comment: Not the original question, but do you know the `String.replace` method can do all this for you?  `System.out.println("matziplzdpaztp".replaceAll("z.p", "zp"));`

Answer (score 2):

Because *in* the loop:

```
if (mat.charAt(i) == 'z' & mat.charAt(i + 2) == 'p'){
// -----------------------------------^^^^^
```

If `i` were bound by `i < mat.length()`, then `i + 2` would be out of bounds.

Answer (score 0):

Because you don't have to reach the end of your sentence since your words are at least three letters long.

Answer (score 0):

mat.length() will give length 14 and if you check for mat.charAt(i + 2) at the end it will give `java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` because the string counts from index 0 not from 1. If you still want to use mat.length() you have to replace the AND '&' operator with short circuit AND '&&' operator in if condition.

Answer (score 0):

"2" stands for "the length except the first word",you just need to check all the positions in the string variable , and treat the positions as the first word of the substring , so just ignore the **"length of the substring without the first word"**.

in your case , the length of "z*p" is 3, you just check all the position in the string , and treat the position as z to check something ,so just ignore "*p" ,which has length 2.